# mvc3 jquery ui tabs stacking up against each other

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-tabs

I am using the jquery tabs on http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default .. The Tabs are located in the masterpage top section, the issue that I get 50% of the time is that as I browse paged within my site the Tabs stack on top of each other instead of being like

- **tab-tab-tab**

its gets like

- **tab**
- **tab**
- **tab**
  and it messes up the entire page what I have thuse far is this in the header

  ```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#tabs").tabs();
   });
  </script>
  ```

  then this in the body

- example 1
- example 2
- example 3

`<div id="tabs-1">
      @Html.Partial("_try")
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
      @Html.Partial("_see")
        </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
      @Html.Partial("_mine")
      </div>`

its not the _partial since I have replaced them with regular text as well..what can it possibly be..

Comment: Maybe referencing multiple version of jquery (1.5.1 and 1.9.1) causing the problem.

Comment: Agreed -- remove the jquery 1.5.1 reference and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, as it turned out it was the Adsense code interacting with the Tabs that was causing all these issues.